# Proof of closure property $a \in Cl\ A \iff \forall r > 0\ B_r(a) \cap A \neq \emptyset$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

> $a \in Cl\  A \iff \forall r > 0\  B_r(a) \cap A \neq \emptyset$

$Cl\  A$ is an intersection of all closed sets, containing $A$.

Can somebody give me a proof of this fact?

Comment: Did you try to prove it yourself? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: You might want to mention your definition of $\operatorname{Cl} (A)$. Is it the intersection of all closed subsets that include $A$? Is it the union of $A$ and the set of all accumulation points of $A$? Is it the union of $A$ and the boundary of $A$? The definitions are all equivalent, but it might help others on here while they are constructing arguments.

Comment: So prove $a$ in set $A$ or it's boundary $iff$ for all balls centered on $a$ intersection with $A$ is not empty? Plus one for being formal :). If $a \in A$ well then it's simple so really have to show it for open $A$'s.

Comment: @martin.koeberl For $\Rightarrow$ it seems like I have to use the fact $B_r(a) \subset  X\setminus A$, but I'm not sure if it is the right statement.

Comment: For $a$ not in $A$'s* @Nunya I think that is really good point because the definition implies the one implication.

Comment: @Negligible Senescence I dont see how $B_r(a) \subset X \setminus A$ because some $B_r(a) \in A$?

Comment: @marshalcraft I picked $x = a$ for $B_r(a) = \{x \in X\ |\ \rho(x, a) < r \} \forall r > 0$. Then $x = a \in A \subset Cl\ A$. So the $\Leftarrow$ is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right side is, essentially, saying that $a$ is either in $A$ or a limit point of $A$.

For $\impliedby$: Since all the sets which are intersection'd contain $a$ and are closed, they must also contain $A$'s limit points, and thus contain $a$.

For $\implies$: This becomes simple once you realize that $\text{Cl}\;A$ contains only $A$ and its limit points. If $a$ isn't a limit point (that is, $a \in A$), the right hand statement is true, because all balls centered around $a$ contain $a$ (the distance from $a$ to itself is 0, less than all possible $r$). Meanwhile, if $a$ is a limit point, then the right side must be satisfied, because the right side says the exact same thing.

Comment: For $\Leftarrow$ direction: Is it enough to say that we can see that all intersections contain element $a \in A$. Then, since $A \subset Cl\ A$ it follows that $a$ is also in $Cl\ A$.
We only now that $B_r(a)$ is open, I don't really see why $B_r(a) \cap A$ is closed...